# base & current vs base & offset?

Tags: python, attributes

I have an `Attribute` class, which can represent different attributes like `speed` or `armor`. `Attribute` has a `base`, an `offset` and a `current` value.
This is easiest explained using examples, I'll use `speed` as an example.

`speed = Attribute()`.
Now speed has a `base` value, it's simply the speed that our player moves at.
When I equip better running shoes for the player, he gets f.e. 50 of additional speed. This means that `offset` will bet set to `50`.
Now when someone throws a spell that slows you by 10, the offset will become `50 - 10 = 40`.
The attribute class would look something like this:

```
class Attribute(object):
    def __init__(self, base):
        self.base = base
        self.offset = 0

    @property
    def current(self):
        return self.base + self.offset

    @current.setter
    def current(self, value):
        self.offset = 0 - (self.base - value)
```

Now an other way to represent this would be using `base` and `current` and have `offset` as a property:

```
class Attribute(object):
    def __init__(self, base):
         self.base = base
         self.current = base

    @property
    def offset(self):
         return 0 - (self.base - self.current)

    @offset.setter
    def offset(self, value):
         self.current = self.health + value
```

They both work the exact same way, is there a reason to use one over the other?

Comment: It is absolutely a personal opinion: but for getting, and setting the current speed makes more sense, than do these with the offset. For me it is more straightforward.

Comment: `0 - (self.base - value)` — why not just `value - self.base`?

Comment: Depends on what operations are likely to be performed most often. If changing the offset happens more often than fetching the current value, then store the offset. I suspect it's the other way around: you fetch the current much more often than you change it, so store the current.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As mentioned by [@Lee Daniel Crocker](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2192494/lee-daniel-crocker) in the comments, it all depends on which operation you adjust more.
Do you change `current` more often than you change `offset`?
There's no preferred way in Python, but there *might* be one in your program.

According to your examples, it seems like you're creating a game where people interact with others.
You mentioned `armor`, `speed`, player, and getting hit by a slowing spell.
When your player gets slowed by a spell, you don't want to *set* his `speed` to something, you want to *reduce* it.
This is easily done with the offset, that's exactly what it's used for.
However, this can also be done with the current, and the code is exact same for both, even tho the meaning is different: `speed.current -= 10`.

If you'd like to do a relative slow (say, slow him by 10% instead of 10mph), you would probably use the current value again: `speed.current *= 0.9`.
Then again, both of these can be achieved with the `offset` version:

```
speed.offset -= 10 // reduce by 10
speed.offset = speed.current * 0.9 - speed.base // reduce by 10%
```

As we see here, using `current` makes the code easier to read when using relative slowing, and most people will find `speed.current -= 50` more obvious than `speed.offset -= 50`. It's also faster to use `current` when doing relative slowing, since less stuff is calculated.

So, you might need both quite often, and neither is superior over the other.
I would still say the same as Crocker said, go with `current`, it's probably easier to understand for everyone, and much cleaner when doing relative slowing.

Comment: The general point of this answer is right, but I think there's a risk if you mix additive modifiers and multiplicative ones that you'll have offsets accumulating that you don't want. For instance if a player changes shoes while slowed, their speed might be permanently changed if they change them back again after the slow has worn off. That's because this sequence of operations `x *= 0.9; x += 5; x /= 0.9; x -= 5` doesn't result in `x` having the value it had at the beginning. So if you want to have multiplicative modifiers, you may want them to be in a separate `factor` variable.

Answer (score 0):

I'd prefer the first variant, where `base` and `offset` are the real values and `current` is the computed effective value. However, I wouldn't add a setter, because it is ambiguous whether that setter should set the base value or the offset. Leave the effective value as read-only instead.

Also, I would at least consider making the modifiers a list, which could be easier to implement and debug. Consider adding the sneakers of speed, giving a +50. Then, drinking a potion of quickness, giving +10%. Then you take off the sneakers again and finally the potion runs out. If you make this code correct with your approach, it will have all the logic externally to the property in the places where the property is modified. This is just my gut feeling, you will have to make that decision yourself, because only you know the real code and what it should do.